# How do I create classes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I want to know if there is any way if I can create a class, write some functions inside the class, create object and then call the functions from the class using that object in JavaScript. For Example:

Suppose this is my `script.js` file which contains the class and methods:

```
class Myclass {

  function method1() {
    alert("This is method 1");
  }

}
```

Suppose this is my `index.html` file:

```
<head>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  Myclass obj = new Myclass();

  <input type="button" onclick="obj.method1();" value="Click Here">

</body>
```

Comment: A "class" is an object in JS.

Comment: This may be useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xizFJHKHdHw

Comment: `Myclass obj` is invalid syntax. Please remember that JavaScript is dynamically typed. Use `var`, `const`, or `let` instead.

Comment: It was just an example. We use the keyword 'class' in other programming languages to declare a class. I want to know how can we do that in JavaScript.

Comment: It might be confusing, but javascript isn't a class based language, however it does have objects, you just don't create objects the same way as you do in a class based paradigm.

Comment: You need to learn the fundamentals of JS. It's not like other languages which "have classes".

Comment: @D.Foley JS is not a class based language, but it has constructors and prototypes, and ES2015 introduced classes to JS as syntactic sugar.

Comment: @evolutionxbox JS does have classes with the release of ES2015.

Comment: @AndrewLi I understand JS has the keyword "class", but it is still prototypal inheritance.

Comment: Your index is wrong. All you Javascript should be enclosed between `<script></script>` tags.

Comment: I agree it has "classes", but I also believe the user should understand the fundamentals of JS, as per the question he seems to be looking to code in the same way you would in java, when calling a method in JS is normally done in a whole different way

Comment: A tiny bit of Google searching will show you more than a hundred reference web sites where you can read all about the Javascript object/class syntax.  Here's one for starters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes.  You really shouldn't be coming here first before doing your own research on the language.  You should come here AFTER you've done your own research and when you got stuck or confused about a particular issue you have already researched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) are introduced in ECMAScript 2015, and are just syntactic sugar over constructor functions. In other words, this is what it should look like:

```
class Myclass {

  method1() {
    alert("This is method 1");
  }

}
```

Method declarations in ES2015 do not have the `function` keyword (because they are methods). Then you can create an instance like so:

```
const instance = new Myclass();
instance.method1();
```

You can use `var`, `let`, or `const`. JavaScript is a weakly-typed language so there are no type declarations in assignments.

Answer (score -1):

In JS you wouldn't call a method like that, you would declare the function in the js file and call it directly, like this:

```
function showAlert(){
    alert('MyAlert');
}
```

and in your html code:

```
 <h1 id="title">Javascript example no.1</h1>
<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="ShowAlert" onclick="showAlert()"/>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rgL91upa/1/

Much simpler than with classes :)